# Error with Vaadin / Webpack in Development mode on MacOS 12 Monterey on M1

Tags: macos, vaadin, webpack-dev-server, vaadin21

Since upgrading to MacOS 12 / Monterey I encounter an error, when trying to run my application in Development mode.

To verify the problem, I created a completely new Starter App from start.vaadin.com.
I used JDK 11 and Vaadin 21 as that is what my other projects use.

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate for development

When I try to start my project from within IntelliJ as I've done this multiple times before, the project starts, begins to compile the frontend as usual, is writing "Frontend compiled successfully" and then fails with the following message

```
2021-11-05 08:29:09.589 ERROR 11463 --- [        webpack] c.v.base.devserver.DevModeHandlerImpl    : Error when reading manifest.json from webpack-dev-server

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:600) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:372) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1299) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1232) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1120) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1051) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1653) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevModeHandlerImpl.readManifestPaths(DevModeHandlerImpl.java:556) ~[vaadin-dev-server-8.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevModeHandlerImpl.processLine(DevModeHandlerImpl.java:492) ~[vaadin-dev-server-8.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevModeHandlerImpl.readLinesLoop(DevModeHandlerImpl.java:457) ~[vaadin-dev-server-8.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevModeHandlerImpl.lambda$logStream$2(DevModeHandlerImpl.java:428) ~[vaadin-dev-server-8.0.3.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

and I can't access the webpage. When starting in production mode from the command line everything is working fine.

Can anyone provide me with some pointers what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Node 17, then you are hitting this issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/12246 and the solution is to use Node 16 instead

Comment: Why is it working in the Beta of Vaadin 22 though?

Answer (score 1):

Same here but on MacOS Catalina (doesn't think this depends on MacOS version). I've detect that problem while build and run the Vaadin starter app from Eclipse, which didn't work. I don't know which node version is picked up by Eclipse. I've set 16 as default via `nvm alias default 16` but no luck. If one use the command line, with such tools like nvm we can fine grained tune the node setup. Here my results:

Vaadin: 21.0.3 Node: 16.13.0 ✅
Vaadin: 21.0.4 Node: 16.13.10 ✅
Vaadin: 21.0.4 Node: 17.1.0 ❌

my `nvm ls` results in:

```
>nvm ls
->     v16.13.0
        v17.1.0
         system
default -> 16 (-> v16.13.0)
node -> stable (-> v17.1.0) (default)
stable -> 17.1 (-> v17.1.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> v16.13.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.7 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.18.1 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.13.0
```